# Working properly with sum() function and relation table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have created following 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Name` ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` INTEGER );
insert into `Name` VALUES(1,'test1');
insert into `Name` VALUES(2,'test2');


CREATE TABLE "Table1" ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `nameID` INTEGER, `amnt1` INTEGER, `amnt2` INTEGER, `amnt3` INTEGER, `amnt4` INTEGER, `amnt5` INTEGER, `amnt6` INTEGER, `entryDate` TEXT );
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-04-01');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(NULL,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-05-06');

CREATE TABLE "Table2" ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `nameID` INTEGER, `amnt1` INTEGER, `amnt2` INTEGER, `amnt3` INTEGER, `amnt4` INTEGER, `amnt5` INTEGER, `amnt6` INTEGER, `entryDate` TEXT );
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-04-02');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-05-05');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(NULL,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,'2018-05-06');


CREATE TABLE "Table3" ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `nameID` INTEGER, `amnt1` INTEGER, `amnt2` INTEGER, `amnt3` INTEGER, `amnt4` INTEGER, `amnt5` INTEGER, `amnt6` INTEGER, `entryDate` TEXT );
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-04-02');
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES(NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'2018-05-05');
```

I am trying to addition Table1 columns data matching with Table2(For example Table1.amnt1+Table2.amnt1) columns. Then Add Table3 for summing.

I am not a expert Database admin, i have tried:

```
SELECT sum(amnt1),sum(amnt2),sum(amnt3),sum(amnt4),sum(amnt5),sum(amnt6) 
FROM (select 
      Table1.amnt1+Table2.amnt1 as amnt1,Table1.amnt2+Table2.amnt2 as amnt2,Table1.amnt3+Table2.amnt3 as amnt3,
      Table1.amnt4+Table2.amnt4 as amnt4,Table1.amnt5+Table2.amnt5 as amnt5,Table1.amnt6+Table2.amnt6 as amnt6
      FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.nameID=Table2.nameID
      where Table1.entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20'

      UNION ALL 
      select amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6 
      FROM Table3 
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20' )
```

It gives  wrong calculation. I am seeing in relational sub query  am not using entryDate. Seems my query is not correct.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6b3ab/8)

Comment: Define "matching". And show the expected result for the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply extend `UNION ALL` part:

```
SELECT sum(amnt1),sum(amnt2),sum(amnt3),sum(amnt4),sum(amnt5),sum(amnt6) 
FROM (select amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6 
      FROM Table1 
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6 
      FROM Table2
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20' 
      UNION ALL 
      select amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6 
      FROM Table3 
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20'     
     ) s
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6b3ab/11/0)**

## EDIT:

> what if each tables has some different columns? For example Table2 has amnt1,amnt2,amount7,amnt9. If these columns name does not exist in Table1 or table3 then i want to get the exisiting data.

Then you simply put 0 as that place (here example of amt7 available only in table2):

```
SELECT sum(amnt1),sum(amnt2),sum(amnt3),sum(amnt4),sum(amnt5),sum(amnt6),
       sum(amt7) 
FROM (select amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6,0 AS amt7
      FROM Table1 
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6,amt7
      FROM Table2
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20' 
      UNION ALL 
      select amnt1,amnt2,amnt3,amnt4,amnt5,amnt6,0
      FROM Table3 
      where entryDate between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-20'     
     ) s
```

Comment: what if each tables has some different columns? For example Table2 has amnt1,amnt2,amount7,amnt9. If these columns name does not exist in Table1 or table3 then i want to get the exisiting data.

Comment: @kodr Then just put 0.